# problem while trying to call my API - AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I found the response :
I just forgot to parse the response into json using Gson in loginAction() method

```
private fun loginAction(user: String)
    {
        UserService.userLogin(user, {
            response ->
            val token = response.header("x-auth")
            val userData = Gson().fromJson(response.body()!!.string(), User::class.java)
            createUserSession(baseContext, userData, token)

            this.openHomeActivity()
        },
        {
            error ->
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString())
        })
    }
```

I am trying to add a login activity to my mobile application, using an external API to check email and password.
I use OkHttp 3.14.0 to connect to the API, but I am getting that error when I try to connect my user :

```
2019-04-02 13:37:10.630 5118-5176/fr.myapp.firstapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: fr.myapp.firstapp, PID: 5118
    java.lang.Error: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1173)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
        at fr.myapp.firstapp.LoginActivity$loginAction$1.invoke(LoginActivity.kt:44)
        at fr.myapp.firstapp.LoginActivity$loginAction$1.invoke(LoginActivity.kt:15)
        at fr.myapp.firstapp.network.UserService$Companion$userLogin$1.onResponse(UserService.kt:21)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:174)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

here is my login activity :

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var usernameInput: EditText
    lateinit var passwordInput: EditText
    lateinit var loginBtn: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity)

        this.usernameInput = findViewById(R.id.login_username_input)
        this.passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input)
        this.loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_action_btn)

        loginBtn.setOnClickListener { this.loginAction(this.loginInfo()) }
    }

    private fun openHomeActivity()
    {
        val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    private fun loginAction(user: String)
    {
        UserService.userLogin(user, {
            response ->
            val jsonData: String = response.body()!!.string()
            val userObj = JSONObject(jsonData)

            createUserSession(this, userObj)
            this.openHomeActivity()
        },
        {
            error ->
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString())
        })
    }

    private fun loginInfo(): String
    {
        val username: String = this.usernameInput.text.toString()
        val password: String = this.passwordInput.text.toString().sha512()
        val data = JSONObject()
            .put("username", username)
            .put("password", password)

        return data.toString()
    }
}
```

and my user service :

```
class UserService {
    companion object {
        private val JSON = MediaType.get("application/json; charset=utf-8")

        fun userLogin(data: String, success: (success: Response) -> Unit, failure: (error: IOException) -> Unit)
        {
            val body = RequestBody.create(this.JSON, data)
            val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                .url(UrlBuilder.api + "/user/login")
                .post(body)
                .build()

            OkHttpClient().newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) = success(response)
                override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) = failure(e)
            })
        }
}
```

I also added the authorisation to connect to the Internet in my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Thank you for your help

PS : sorry for my english, this is not my primary language

Comment: Is your error in request or in response ?

Comment: @VivekMishra I guess it is in response but I am not sure... how can I know that ?

Comment: The exception is caused by `JSONObject(jsonData)` because `jsonData` is an empty string (the exception is "end of input at character 0). Did you check whether the server responds with a JSON (e.g., via Postman or another external tool)?

Comment: @user2340612 Hi, yes I tried with Postman and it worked.
I found the solution : I just forgot to parse my response with Gson in the loginAction() method

Answer (score 0):

I found the response : I just forgot to parse the response into json using Gson in loginAction() method

```
private fun loginAction(user: String)
    {
        UserService.userLogin(user, {
            response ->
            val token = response.header("x-auth")
            val userData = Gson().fromJson(response.body()!!.string(), User::class.java)
            createUserSession(baseContext, userData, token)

            this.openHomeActivity()
        },
        {
            error ->
            Log.d("ERROR", error.toString())
        })
    }
```